# How to display a list of nested hashmaps in spring view

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring. I have a list that holds nested LinkedHashMaps in it.

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> columnMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> columnGroupMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> rowMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>();
    List<LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>> rowList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>>();

    columnMap.put("row1xcolumn1", "value1");
    columnGroupMap.put("summary", columnMap);
    rowMap.put("Row1", columnGroupMap);
    :
    columnMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    columnMap.put("row2xcolumn1", "value1");
    columnGroupMap.put("summary", columnMap);
    rowMap.put("Row2", columnGroupMap);
    :
    rowList.add(rowMap);
    model.addAttribute("rowList", rowList);
```

I had stored the values in the hashmaps and finally the rowMap is added to the rowList. I need to print the key-value from columnMap in the view. Here is the code I have in view:

```
    <c:forEach var="rowMap" items="${rowList}" varStatus="rowList">
      <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${rowMap['summary']}" var="rowColumnMap"  varStatus="rowColumnMap">             
          <c:forEach items="${rowColumnMap}" var="fieldCol" varStatus="columnMap">
            <th class="tableHeaderCellSummary">
              ${fieldCol.key} = ${fieldCol.value}
            </th>
          </c:forEach>

        </c:forEach>                                    
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

I am not able to see the rows generated in the page. Please help me to define the view.

Also is there a way to get the columnMap value directly without iterating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the rowList, I passed rowMap and got it worked!!! 
Here is the change in controller code:

```
    //List<LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>> rowList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>>();
    //model.addAttribute("rowList", rowList);
    model.addAttribute("rowMap", rowMap);
```

Here is the view code:

```
    <c:forEach var="rowMapVar" items="${rowMap}">
    <tr>
      <td class="tableCell" style="text-align: left;" nowrap>&nbsp;New Test Case&nbsp;</td>
      <c:forEach items="${rowMapVar.value['summary']}" var="hSummaryTC">
        <td class="tableCell" style="text-align: center;">${hSummaryTC.value}</td>
      </c:forEach>                                              
    </tr>
```